# Global fit using nlsLM

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a difference of Gamma functions to some fMRI data. Here is the function I am trying to fit:

```
# Difference of Gamma distributions to model HRF
DiffGammas <- function(x, w, ww, a, aa, b, bb) {
  y1 = w*((b^a*x^(a-1)*exp(-x*b))/gamma(a))
  y2 = (1-ww)*((bb^aa*x^(aa-1)*exp(-x*bb))/gamma(aa))
  y = y1-y2;
  return(y)
}
```

Here the data:

```
Run t   y
1   0   0.032003192
1   1   0.035247903
1   2   0.075404794
1   3   0.246668665
1   4   0.43784297
1   5   0.48204744
1   6   0.306346753
1   7   0.143187816
1   8   0.057954844
1   9   0.013958918
1   10  0.022630042
1   11  -0.00735287
1   12  -0.055431955
1   13  -0.11563044
1   14  -0.155657944
1   15  -0.146548568
1   16  -0.086195647
1   17  -0.048550909
1   18  0.016424371
1   19  0.049021839
1   20  0.012366969
1   21  -0.03851945
1   22  -0.071969113
1   23  -0.044332852
2   0   0.08518882
2   1   0.110297941
2   2   0.185532434
2   3   0.352716178
2   4   0.53645537
2   5   0.599135887
2   6   0.443617796
2   7   0.275094048
2   8   0.179031458
2   9   0.118620937
2   10  0.111958314
2   11  0.072388446
2   12  -0.004448448
2   13  -0.058529647
2   14  -0.086651798
2   15  -0.085788373
2   16  -0.032654685
2   17  0.020878978
2   18  0.104788051
2   19  0.169295268
2   20  0.101337921
2   21  0.021178963
2   22  -0.025350047
2   23  -0.053233691
3   0   0.058608233
3   1   0.096408759
3   2   0.194452044
3   3   0.374613189
3   4   0.570983267
3   5   0.572352346
3   6   0.417996955
3   7   0.257623921
3   8   0.16186917
3   9   0.116943452
3   10  0.119766292
3   11  0.064198058
3   12  -0.013711493
3   13  -0.095039932
3   14  -0.105732843
3   15  -0.085641436
3   16  -0.041355324
3   17  0.001644888
3   18  0.037273866
3   19  0.03784796
3   20  0.004481299
3   21  -0.0216824
3   22  -0.020064194
3   23  -0.039836136
4   0   0.068518121
4   1   0.08325848
4   2   0.13751084
4   3   0.276952687
4   4   0.473697571
4   5   0.49691874
4   6   0.37607162
4   7   0.243455766
4   8   0.161476939
4   9   0.132455191
4   10  0.154391828
4   11  0.138457915
4   12  0.120507831
4   13  0.049945217
4   14  0.002031973
4   15  -0.009507957
4   16  0.052133462
4   17  0.107326776
4   18  0.153646926
4   19  0.15333057
4   20  0.107420992
4   21  0.038419348
4   22  0.009900797
4   23  -0.026444602
```

Where 'Run' is the type of stimulus, 't' is the time and 'y' is the BOLD signal. I want to compare a model in which Run 1-4 each has a separate set of parameters (model14) with a global model in which Runs 1-4 have the same parameters (model0).

model0 converges and works fine:

```
## Global fit (one curve for all data sets)
fo <- y ~ DiffGammas(t, w, ww, a, aa, b, bb)
model0 <- NULL
model0 <- nlsLM(fo,
           data = mydata,
           subset = Run %in% 1:4,
           start = as.data.frame(rbind(coef(m1))), 
           trace = T)
summary(model0)
```

'start' in this case is:

```
        w        ww        a       aa        b       bb
1 1.769255 0.3870352 10.67308 92.03272 2.163427 6.408473
```

parameters have been estimated with an individual fit (m1) to Run 1 with the same 'DiffGammas' function.

However, when I try to fit a model with a different set of paramters for each Run:

```
model14 <- NULL
model14 <- nlsLM(y ~ DiffGammas(t, w[Run], ww[Run], a[Run], aa[Run], b[Run], bb[Run]),
           data = mydata,
           subset = Run %in% 1:4,
           start = as.data.frame(rbind(coef(m1), coef(m2), coef(m3), coef(m4))),
           trace = T)
summary(model14)
```

start in this case is:

```
         w        ww         a        aa         b       bb
1 1.769255 0.3870352 10.673081  92.03272 2.1634274 6.408473
2 2.857442 1.4833173  6.072707 139.16018 1.1338433 7.297339
3 2.868868 0.6270769  5.665530 132.47579 1.0744604 9.449620
4 2.721601 1.6320522  4.703770 138.55078 0.8022566 7.463612
```

with parameters been estimated with separate fits to Runs 1-4 with the same 'DiffGammas' function.

Running this last bit of code I get the following errors and I am not sure how to deal with them:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix(out$hessian, nrow = length(unlist(par))) :
  data length [36] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [24]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Best,
Andrea

Comment: That looks like a weird way to do start parameters. According to the manual: `start: a named list or named numeric vector of starting estimates.` I'm pretty sure you should only have one start value per parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sirius. Actually I've tried different solutions including: start = as.data.frame(rbind(coef(m1))) - one starting value for each paramter but it does retunr the following error:Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

Comment: You just can't vectorize your formula and your start parameters like this, you have to run them one `Run` at a time, using plain names, with a specific set of start values each time. It's not hard.

Comment: Thank you Sirius. Can you please better explain yourself with an example? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the rest of the data as they were,

```r
start2 <- read.table(text=
"         w        ww         a        aa         b       bb
1 1.769255 0.3870352 10.673081  92.03272 2.1634274 6.408473
2 2.857442 1.4833173  6.072707 139.16018 1.1338433 7.297339
3 2.868868 0.6270769  5.665530 132.47579 1.0744604 9.449620
4 2.721601 1.6320522  4.703770 138.55078 0.8022566 7.463612
", header=TRUE )

models14 <- lapply( 1:nrow(start2), function(i) {
    try( nlsLM( fo, data=mydata, start=start2[i,], subset = Run == i, trace=TRUE ) )
})
```

You will probably see, like me, that start parameter set 2 and 4 fails to produce a model.